# Upload Images and files with TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

In my symfony2 project I use TidyMCE in my textareas, to be able to insert news from the backend. News can have images in the content or files links to pdf files to display. I am new to this and I can not upload the images or files, so that I can search the different folders and once selected a copy is made on the server.

I've been looking at a lot of comments, but I'm kind of bundled up. I have seen on the web of tinymceel following code:

**Basic Local File Picker**

```
  tinymce.init({
  selector: '#editor',
  plugins: 'image code',
    toolbar: 'undo redo | link image | code',
    // enable title field in the Image dialog
    image_title: true, 
    // enable automatic uploads of images represented by blob or data URIs
    automatic_uploads: true,
    // URL of our upload handler (for more details check:       https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#images_upload_url)
    images_upload_url: 'postAcceptor.php',
    // here we add custom filepicker only to Image dialog
    file_picker_types: 'image', 
    // and here's our custom image picker
    file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
      var input = document.createElement('input');
      input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
      input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

      // Note: In modern browsers input[type="file"] is functional without 
      // even adding it to the DOM, but that might not be the case in some older
      // or quirky browsers like IE, so you might want to add it to the DOM
      // just in case, and visually hide it. And do not forget do remove it
      // once you do not need it anymore.

      input.onchange = function() {
        var file = this.files[0];

        // Note: Now we need to register the blob in TinyMCEs image blob
        // registry. In the next release this part hopefully won't be
        // necessary, as we are looking to handle it internally.
        var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
        var blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
        var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file);
        blobCache.add(blobInfo);

        // call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name
      cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
      };

      input.click();
    }
  });
```

**PHP Upload Handler**

```
 <?php
   /*******************************************************
    * Only these origins will be allowed to upload images *
    ******************************************************/
   $accepted_origins = array("http://localhost", "http://192.168.1.1", "http://example.com");

   /*********************************************
    * Change this line to set the upload folder *
    *********************************************/
   $imageFolder = "images/";

   reset ($_FILES);
   $temp = current($_FILES);
   if (is_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'])){
     if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
       // same-origin requests won't set an origin. If the origin is set, it must be valid.
       if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $accepted_origins)) {
         header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
  } else {
         header("HTTP/1.0 403 Origin Denied");
         return;
       }
     }

     /*
       If your script needs to receive cookies, set images_upload_credentials : true in
       the configuration and enable the following two headers.
     */
     // header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
     // header('P3P: CP="There is no P3P policy."');

     // Sanitize input
     if (preg_match("/([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).])|([\.]{2,})/", $temp['name'])) {
         header("HTTP/1.0 500 Invalid file name.");
         return;
     }

     // Verify extension
     if (!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($temp['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), array("gif", "jpg", "png"))) {
         header("HTTP/1.0 500 Invalid extension.");
         return;
     }

     // Accept upload if there was no origin, or if it is an accepted origin
     $filetowrite = $imageFolder . $temp['name'];
     move_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'], $filetowrite);

     // Respond to the successful upload with JSON.
     // Use a location key to specify the path to the saved image resource.
     // { location : '/your/uploaded/image/file'}
     echo json_encode(array('location' => $filetowrite));
   } else {
     // Notify editor that the upload failed
     header("HTTP/1.0 500 Server Error");
   }
 ?>
```

But I do not quite understand where to put the postAcceptor.php or referred to with `{location: '/ your / uploaded / image / file'}`.

I'm a little lost, please thank all the possible help

Comment: I don't see any symfony in this. Can you clarify the problem?

Answer (score 0):

postacceptor is your server side method for accepting the file and uploading it in your server. I am using mvc so I created a custom route "ImageUpload". and I use that instead. 
location part is the expected return from your method. this will replace the file location/referrer a.k.a src tag when you use images_reuse_filename = true.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use symphony but according to your code you would put the postAcceptor file in the same directory as form